# Warning in query plan "Cardinality Estimate"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, type-conversion, cardinality-estimates

```sql-here
create table T(ID int identity primary key)
insert into T default values
insert into T default values

go

select cast(ID as varchar(10)) as ID
from T
where ID = 1
```

The query above has a warning in the query plan.

```xml
<Warnings>
  <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" Expression="CONVERT(varchar(10),[xx].[dbo].[T].[ID],0)" />
</Warnings>
```

Why does it have the warning?

How could a cast in the field list affect the cardinality estimate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This warning was new for SQL Server 2012.

From
[New "Type Conversion in Expression....." warning in SQL2012 ,to noisy to practical use](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695556/new-type-conversion-in-expression-warning-in-sql2012-to-noisy-to-practical-use)

> I see what you mean. While I agree that this is noise in most cases,
>   it is low priority for us to fix. We will look at it if we get more
>   feedback. For now I have closed this by design.

Connect was killed and it doesn’t look like the original issue was transferred to UserVoice. Here’s a different UserVoice issue about the same problem, [Type conversion in may affect CardinalityEstimate - Convert/cast on selected columns](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/32895910)

I will provide the boring answer until someone comes along with a better one.

> Why does it have the warning?

Speculation on my part.
There is a cast on a column that is used in the where clause which make statistics of that column interesting. A change of datatype makes the statistics no good so lets warn about that in case the value from the field list might end up to be used somewhere.

> How could a cast in the field list affect the cardinality estimate?

It can't unless it is the field list in a derived table.

Comment: I would append the following to the last sentence, *or the query is a view definition and queries will filter on the column showing the warning, in question*.