# Datetime to formatted Date Implicit Conversion

Tags: sql-server, cardinality-estimates

I am looking at implicit conversions in my stored procedures and the biggest one I have in my prod database is a warning by the Cardinality Estimator in SQL 2014 for converting datetime to formatted date.

I have read the following questions:
[Warning in query plan "Cardinality Estimate"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33528/warning-in-query-plan-cardinality-estimate) and 
[DateTime to Format: Implicit Conversion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161858/datetime-to-format-implicit-conversion) but these fail to mention that FORMAT() removes the warning they are only describing that the problem won't be fixed, which is not a solution I looking for, FORMAT() is a viable solution.

Previously we used the formatting option on CONVERT() to format the date, but ANYTIME I use CONVERT() I get an implicit conversion.

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [Birthdate] datetime )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( N'1891-12-30T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1918-10-31T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1917-12-21T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1906-10-29T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1916-12-12T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1916-11-08T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1918-10-01T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1913-03-18T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1920-08-03T00:00:00' ), 
( N'1919-10-22T00:00:00' )


SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),t.Birthdate,109) AS varConvert,
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(26), t.Birthdate, 109) AS nvarConvert,
        TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(26),t.Birthdate, 109) AS tryCon,
        FORMAT(t.Birthdate, 'MMM dd yyyy') AS form
FROM #temptable AS t

DROP TABLE #temptable
```

The only not implicit conversion to a formatted date is the FORMAT() function:

[image]

Is there a way to not use the FORMAT() function and continue using the Convert function to return formatted dates? Ie do i need to extend or reduce the length of my formatted dates during conversion. I want to avoid implicit conversions, but re-writting all CONVERT() to FORMAT() will take more testing than changing the current CONVERT functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted does indeed produce PlanAffectingConvert warnings in SQL Server 2016 SP1 (didn't try on earlier versions).

That's a bug - those convert statements shouldn't be throwing that warning since it doesn't affect cardinality in any way when they're just in the SELECT portion.

File a bug report for it at http://connect.microsoft.com and include your repro code, and edit your question to include a link to the Connect item so folks can upvote it.

Comment: Or vote for this one [New "Type Conversion in Expression....." warning in SQL2012 ,to noisy to practical use](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695556/new-type-conversion-in-expression-warning-in-sql2012-to-noisy-to-practical-use)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Microsoft killed Connect and your link is broke. Can you please help update it?